# Распаковка файла

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать лучше, или правильнее.
У меня имеется файл.zip который скачивается автоматически, при этом у нас запущенно приложение. Его имя к примеру: `Build.exe`, теперь нужно распаковать этот файл.zip в место, где находится `Build.exe` НО, возникает вопрос, как это сделать правильно?

```cs
filder_Build = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
if (Directory.Exists(filder_Build))
{
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("тут путь где лежит файл.zip", filder_Build);
}
```

Я думал сначала убить процесс, потом удалить файл, и сразу же распаковать,  но, так не работает...

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? И зачем убивать процесс?

Comment: @timur То и значит, не работает так как хотел сделать.

Comment: А как делает???

Comment: @timur, Что-то не пойму сути ваших вопросов, от слова совсем

Comment: @timur мне нужно при распаковке, распаковыемый файл вернуть на место приложения, которое кстати запущено. По этому и убивал процесс, чтобы не было ошибки: `Такой файл уже существует` Будет глупо, если я сначала удалю рабочее приложение, и потом буду пробовать распаковать, много ЕСЛИ возникает при этом, вот одно из них к примеру, при распаковке, недостаточно места... Или zip файл повредился при скачивании, а приложение рабочее уже было удалено. По этому я пришёл узнать совета, как сделать лучше распаковку файла

Comment: Windows позволяет переименовать файл даже тогда, когда он запущен и эту особенность можно взять за основу, но, это не всегда работает и не на всех системах. По этому, лучше сделать отдельный процесс, который дождется завершения, удалит старое и распакует новое.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не понял, какой отдельный процесс?

Comment: А это уже зависит все от вашей фантазии. Я например делал bat скрипт, некие консольные инструкции и логика была такая: Программа проверяет версию - если новее, то качает архив - распаковывает в отдельную директорию - запускает этот скрипт - закрывается. Скрипт ждет, пока не завершится процесс основной программы - как только завершится, делает замену из временной директории в основную - подчищает весь остаточный мусор - запускает новую версию приложения. То есть не сама программа обновляет файлы, а консоль, отдельное приложение. Вместо консоли может быть и самописное что-то.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Подскажите пожалуйста, при открытом приложении, его можно куда-либо переместить?

Comment: Кого? Приложение? Я вам вроде сказал, что Windows позволит файл переименовать, не более, и то не всегда.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Да я имею ввиду вот что, к примеру пользователь запустил приложение.exe, и это приложение.exe находится на рабочем столе, он нажал кнопку, и оно переместилось на диск `D:/Files` при этом оно может быть открытым?

Comment: Я же вроде дал выше ответ на этот вопрос. Windows позволит его переименовать (и то не всегда), переместить - вряд-ли, может только копию сделать и то не факт (не проверял).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хорошо, а если сделать вот так: Сначала я качаю file.zip распаковываю его в каком-то укромном месте, дальше беру распакованный файл, перемещаю его с помощью `File.Move` при этом меняю название, и запускаю приложение, которое распаковал, остался последний шаг этого всего, как удалить старое приложение?

Comment: Я вам выше говорил, что не всегда система позволяет это сделать. А удалить старое - напишите некую проверку, которое приложение будет делать всегда при запуске и тем самым удалять остатки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так и сделал